# Access to a Matlab gui from the web

Tags: matlab, user-interface, web

Is there a way to place a matlab gui I have on a website, such that users could use or play with, similar to java applets etc? Would I need to compile it differently in some sense?

Answer (score 4):

MATLAB Compiler allows you to create a standalone exe which can be called by your web server using the Common Gateway Interface (CGI).

The CGI script outputs HTML by printing it to the screen (`stdout`). You can input to a CGI script through the environment variable `query_string` . A simple CGI script can be written Using the Matlab functions `getenv` and `fprintf`.

But don't forget to check that you have configured your web server properly in order to run CGI programs, and that you are able to execute a CGI program that is independently.

There's an [example](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-30REEY/index.html) which demonstrates how to do this in Mathworks website.   Perform the following steps to compile and run this example:

1. Compile the MATLAB file into a standalone application. This can be done with the following command in MATLAB: `mcc -m mycgimagic.m`
2. Copy the HTML file to the web server and place it in a directory with the proper permissions. Consult your web server documentation for how to do this.
3. Copy the exe and CTF files to the web server and place them in the "/cgi-bin" directory of your website. You will need to configure the web server to have the proper permissions to be able to execute the exe-file. Consult your web server documentation for how to do this.
4. Install the MCR on the web server.
5. Execute the exe-file for the first time from the web server system itself in order to force the CTF-archive extraction.
6. Load the HTML-file in a web browser from the remote computer and submit the form to execute the CGI program.