# how to query userinput via phone, within matlab

Tags: matlab

Conceptual question:

How can I query userinput via phone (android) within a matlab script running on a server? What would it take to make this work? Could this be achieved using a COM interface like outlook's?

Thanks

Comment: I guess the easiest way is to make a matlab session wait for a tcp/ip packet which then can be sent by any device...

Comment: related, but you could use cgi to access your matlab app from the web (and through your phones webbrowser) [Access to a Matlab gui from the web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099414/access-to-a-matlab-gui-from-the-web)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code I wrote to make this happen, suggestions welcome...

1. install matlab app then...

`%matlab instance #1, run on server`

```
t = tcpip('0.0.0.0', 1234, 'NetworkRole', 'server');
fprintf('server is set up. \n\nwaiting for client to connect... ');
fopen(t);
fprintf('connected.\n')
fprintf('listening for user commands...\n\n');
while true
    if t.BytesAvailable>0
        data = fread(t,t.BytesAvailable);
        if data==1
            disp('1')
        elseif size(data,1)>1 %parse several integers as strings
            switch char(data')
                case 'asdf'
                    disp('do asdf');
                    % >> at this point any input can be run using 'eval' << %
            end
        end
    else
        pause(2); %wait some seconds
    end
end
```

`%matlab instance #2, run on same server`

```
%enable mobile app connection
connector on;
```

`(connect then via mobile app, run following code from the mobile console)`

```
try
    t = tcpip('localhost',1234);
    fclose(t)
    fopen(t)
catch
    fprintf('connection failed.\n');
    return
end
fprintf('connection established.\n')

% send command to server
fwrite(t,'asdf')
```